# Interaction failed with Discord buttons using discord.py and DiscordComponents bot?

Tags: python, button, discord, bots

I'm trying to use a Discord bot to get user interaction on messages through buttons. To do this, I'm using discord.py in tandem with discord_components (seems like it might be outdated now as of a few months ago but not entirely sure).

The buttons are created just fine and appear as expected, but no matter what I try I'm unable to get input and am greeted with "This interaction failed" on each button press:
[discord error]

[image: 1]

Here's the code I'm testing with, taken from Robotic Nation on YT:

```
import discord
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, ComponentsBot, Button, SelectOption, Select
import discord.ext.commands as commands

bot = commands.Bot("!", intents = discord.Intents.all())
ComponentsBot(bot)

@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send("hello", components = [
        [Button(label="Hi", style="3", emoji = "", custom_id="button1")]
        ])
    interaction = await bot.wait_for("button_click")
    await interaction.send(content = "Button clicked!", ephemeral=False)
    

bot.run('user_token (hidden for privacy)')
```

Is there something wrong with this code?

If discord_components is no longer a viable solution, is there another package I can turn to that has a discord bot object and can implement buttons? Since discord.py does not natively support buttons (yet), I'm not entirely sure how to get buttons working with my bot.

I have tried interactions.py, but since that solution uses a "Client" over a bot, I'm forced to refactor a lot of my code which I'm trying to avoid. I'd prefer to use ! commands over / commands too, so a different solution would be preferable. Though I can confirm that interactions.py definitely does have working buttons for me.

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: do you have any errors printed out in the console? I'm not too familiar with discord.py but one thing I suggest is using a event listener for button click then respond that way.

Comment: @JasonMartin No errors at all in the console, just the "interaction failed" when you press the button in discord.

Answer (score 0):

your problem must be your interaction variable. Like i new, it must look like this:

```
interaction = await bot.wait_for(
        "button_click", check=lambda inter: inter.custom_id == "button1"
    )
```

So your command has to look like this:

```
@bot.command()
async def button(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Buttons!", components=[Button(label="Hi", emoji = "", custom_id="button1")])
    interaction = await bot.wait_for(
        "button_click", check=lambda inter: inter.custom_id == "button1"
    )
    await interaction.send(content="Button Clicked")
```

I hope that this will help you